# difference between null and 0 while counting rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query as follows

```
select owner, table_name,num_rows from all_tables
```

for some of the tables `num_rows` is 0 but for some of the table `num_rows` is showing `null`

I'm not getting the difference between these two.

On what condition `null` will come and when 0 will be displayed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the helpful answers and comments I did a little search in the internet to come up with following query

```
ANALYZE TABLE <TABLE_NAME> COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

After executing this query the count is showing 0 for those table which are showing `null` before.

Thank you for all your inputs.

Answer (score 3):

I think `null` is showing on tables without statistics. `Last_analyzed` should be `null` too. Try the query with `Last_analyzed` and check it.

```
select owner, table_name,num_rows, last_analyzed 
from all_tables;
```

Answer (score 2):

this issue because the those table not analyzed first you need to analyzed those tables then statistics apply on them and this may resolve the issue.

Comment: Both Vercelli and Alvaro posted the same answer (probably at the same time, independent of each other), with more details than you gave, and one hour before you. Why did you need to post another, less detailed version of their answer? De-merit from me for these reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In the [ALL_TABLES reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm#REFRN20286) the `NUM_ROWS` column is tagged with an asterisk that points to this note:

> Columns marked with an asterisk (*) are populated only if you collect
>   statistics on the table with the ANALYZE statement or the DBMS_STATS
>   package.